# Looking for an ansatz regarding asymptotics of arccos and arcosh

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, asymptotics

I have to show that

> $$\arccos(x) = \sqrt{2-2x} + O((1-x)^{3/2}) \\
> \text{arcosh}(x) = \sqrt{2x-2} + O((x-1)^{3/2})$$

for $x\to 1^-$ ($x$ approaching 1 from below), $\text{arcosh}(x)$ denotes the inverse of $\cosh(x). $ I tried rewriting it as $\arccos(x) - \sqrt{2-2x} = O((1-x)^{3/2}) $ and then plugging it into the definition, but that didn't quite help since everything got too messy. I don't know what I could rewrite $\arccos(x)$ as either. Any hints?

Comment: Write $x = 1- \varepsilon$ [$1 + \varepsilon$ for the hyperbolic case] and ask yourself for which $\delta$ you have $\cos \delta = 1 - \varepsilon$.

Comment: you can also investigate the asymptotics of $\sqrt{1\pm x^2}^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $x>1$, one has
$$
\begin{align}
\text{arcosh}(x)&=\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1} \right)
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $x \to 1^+$, by the use of a Taylor series expansion, as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$, with $x=1+\varepsilon$,
$$
\begin{align}
\text{arcosh}(x)&=\log\left(1+\varepsilon+\sqrt{(1+\varepsilon)^2-1} \right)
\\&=\log\left(1+\varepsilon+\sqrt{2\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2} \right)
\\&=\left(\varepsilon+\sqrt{2\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2} \right)-\frac12\left(\varepsilon+\sqrt{2\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2} \right)^2+O(\varepsilon^{3/2})
\\&=\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\varepsilon}+O(\varepsilon^{3/2})
\\&=\sqrt{2} \sqrt{x-1} + O((x-1)^{3/2})
\end{align}
$$ as announced.

The same approach applies to $\text{arcos}$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @lappen68 You are welcome.

Comment: Does one have a similar fomula for arccos?

Comment: @lappen68 Yes, one may use $\arccos(x)=- \mathrm{i} \log \left( x+\sqrt{x^2-1} \right)$. Please, have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms

Comment: Alright, I actually thought about that one, however that $i$ confused me a bit. Thanks again!